# Вылетает Sony Vegas Pro при монтаже роликов

Tags: sony-vegas

Каждые несколько минут в работе `SonyVegas Pro 20` программа вылетает без ошибки. Иногда сбрасывается картинка на рабочем столе, иногда компьютер издает сигналы. Предположительно программе не хватает памяти.

На борту `16 Гб` оперативной памяти, `GeForce RTX 2060`, ноутбук. Облазил весь интернет, ничего не помогло. Перепробовал 3 версии Вегаса (17, 18, 20), везде тоже самое.

Перепробовал следующие настройки: объем оперативной памяти ставлю на 0, чтобы программа сама определяла сколько нужно. Видеокарту тоже выключил, иначе выбивает ошибку, связанную с видеокартой. Устанавливал кодеки `LiteCodecPack` и `QuickTime`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь, кто сталкивался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для моего случая решением стало выклчение логов во вкладке `File I/O`. После этого процессор и видеокарта перестали нагружаться и вылеты прекратились.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]